# Which of these ways is better in Java?

Tags: java, class, design-patterns, static, static-methods

I want to create a static class which works like enumeration, but with string values.
Which of the following ways is the safest to extract a full instance of created class?

```
public class Name 
{

    public static final Name MY_NAME = new Name("Chris", "Doe");

    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;

    public Name(firstname, lastname)
    {
        this.firstName = firstname;
        this.lastName = lastname;
    }
}
```

OR

```
public class Name 
{
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;

    public Name(firstname, lastname)
    {
        this.firstName = firstname;
        this.lastName = lastname;
    }

    public static Name myName()
    {
        return new Name("Chris", "Doe");
    }
}
```

Comment: In second pattern why are you using hardcoded values?

Comment: The two aren't identical; the second one will return a new `Name` instance every time `myName()` is called, while the first will return the same instance (barring serialization/concurrency shenanigans)

Comment: The first one would be a better choice as you are creating a final field for the String.

Comment: Are you looking for singleton pattern?

Comment: Neither. I would load it from a properties file.

Comment: If you want to create something which which works like enumeration then why not to use enumeration?

Comment: How are you going to use *my name*?

Comment: I think you need only one instance of the class. Why not make it Singleton?

Comment: NEVER. And I mean NEVER make non-static, non-final fields public as you do in your second example.

Comment: @Dyrborg Nice catch, sir.  Good thing to point out.

Comment: I would say none of them. Try to make the class singleton and its attributes immutable. For any such thing where you deliberately don't want to use enums, rather declare your string constants in an interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to go with the first one, because the first one comprises of `static final Name MY_NAME` **whereas** in the second case a **`new Name` instance** would be returned everytime you call the **`myName() method`** resulting in wastage of memory. So, better go with the first one.

So, to extract a full-instance of a created class, you should go with the first one.

Also,talking about `enum`----in which you hold constant values, your `static field final Name MY_NAME` instance will serve the purpose, you should stick to the first-declaration----thereby supporting your need of enum as well as not wasting memory!

Answer (score 6):

Safest?  I'm not sure what you mean by that.

As far as best-practices go, the second is potentially wasteful, as it will allocate a new instance of `Name` every time `myName()` is invoked.  The other uses a constant, so it conserves more memory.

All of which is relatively trivial in a small application.

If you're trying to have your class emulate an `enum`, the constant is certainly the way to go, as the values of an `enum` are initialized only once.

Just in case you don't know what an `enum` actually is, here would be a sample implementation of your class as one:

```
public enum Name {

    MY_NAME ("Chris", "Doe");

    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;

    private Name(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

... and you could then simply refer to `Name.MY_NAME`.

Comment: Which somewhat begs the question "why not have an enum in the first place", especially when you are hardcoding the values. Even enums can hackily be dynamic in a way.

Comment: @Rogue I agree that you might as well just use an `enum`, but I didn't think that was a suitable answer, haha.

Comment: @JeffGohlke-Nice explanation using `enum` demonstration.

Comment: Worth noting that the `private` modifier on the enum constructor is completely optional as enum constructors are implicitly `private` anyway. It's also a compile-time error to try and set it to anything else.

Comment: @JonK Sure.  I just prefer to be very explicit with my access modifiers. :)

Comment: Oh it's not a criticism, I do exactly the same thing myself - it's just worth mentioning that you don't **have** to do it. :)

Answer (score 0):

go after first method,

create your `public static` instances of class, make your class final so it cant be extended, and make constructor private, so it cannot be instantiate outside of your class

flaw with second method is, your static method `myName` each time creates new instance of Name which is unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

If you only need one object instance with the fixed values why bother having member variables at all?
This way is thread safe regardless of how you use the object.

```
public class Name 
{
    public String getFirstName() {
        return "Chris"
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return "Doe"
    }
}
```

If you must have member variables then:

```
public class Name 
{
    public final String firstName = "Chris"
    public final String lastName = "Doe"
}
```

But as others have suggested just use the enum:

```
public enum Name {
    me("Chris", "Doe");
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    Name(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```